# Fill color the cells of a row between cells containg two specified values

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

On almost every row of a 100+ row worksheet I have a `1` and a `2`.

I would like to automatically shade or fill in color all the cells between the `1` and the `2` for each row, but only when there is both a `1` and a `2`.

Comment: Refer to this formlua in Condiftional Formatting: =$A1+$B1=3, 
http://chuantu.biz/t6/336/1530236356x-1404792307.png, if my understanding is incorrect please provide a sample.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Select the data cells in the table, making sure that `B2` is the active cell, and enter the following for the conditional formatting formula:

```dart
=COUNTIF($A2:A2,1)*COUNTIF(C2:$J2,2)+COUNTIF($A2:A2,2)*COUNTIF(C2:$J2,1)
```

Note that if the data starts in column `A`, that column must be omitted from the selection (and thus the `Applies to` range), and the conditional formatting formula must be entered exactly as above as if the column contained headers and not data.

Also note that the range in the formula deliberately extends one column to the right of the data. This is required for the edge case where a `1` or `2` occurs in the last column.

If more than a single `1` or `2` appears in a row, the formula will do strange things, using the outermost values as the endpoints and occasionally not highlighting an inner `1` or `2`.

Comment: **Robin** this formula will only work when A2 has other than 1 !